# Display "Show more" button to product list in prestashop

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

Currently the code below in the product-list.tpl enables the "add to cart" button when the products don't have attributes and hides the button when the option "Display the add to cart button when a product has attributes" is set to off in the BO. 
My question is how do I need to change this code in order to display the "show details" button. (A button that goes to the product page)

```
<div class="button-container">
{if ($product.id_product_attribute == 0 || (isset($add_prod_display) && ($add_prod_display == 1))) && $product.available_for_order && !isset($restricted_country_mode) && $product.customizable != 2 && !$PS_CATALOG_MODE}
{if (!isset($product.customization_required) || !$product.customization_required) && ($product.allow_oosp || $product.quantity > 0)}
{capture}add=1&amp;id_product={$product.id_product|intval}{if isset($product.id_product_attribute) && $product.id_product_attribute}&amp;ipa={$product.id_product_attribute|intval}{/if}{if isset($static_token)}&amp;token={$static_token}{/if}{/capture}
<a class="button ajax_add_to_cart_button btn btn-default" href="{$link->getPageLink('cart', true, NULL, $smarty.capture.default, false)|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" rel="nofollow" title="{l s='Add to cart'}" data-id-product-attribute="{$product.id_product_attribute|intval}" data-id-product="{$product.id_product|intval}" data-minimal_quantity="{if isset($product.product_attribute_minimal_quantity) && $product.product_attribute_minimal_quantity >= 1}{$product.product_attribute_minimal_quantity|intval}{else}{$product.minimal_quantity|intval}{/if}">
<span>{l s='Add to cart'}</span>
</a>
{else}
<span class="button ajax_add_to_cart_button btn btn-default disabled">
<span>{l s='Add to cart'}</span>
</span>
{/if}
{/if}
<a class="button lnk_view btn btn-default" href="{$product.link|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" title="{l s='View'}">
<span>{if (isset($product.customization_required) && $product.customization_required)}{l s='Customize'}{else}{l s='More'}{/if}</span>
</a>
</div>
```

Thank in advance

Answer (score 1):

Found this to be working.

```
{if $product.id_product_attribute != 0}
                        <a class="btn button"  href="{$product.link|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}">{l s='Λεπτομέριες'}</a>
                        {/if}
```

Hope this is usefull to other users as well

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want a button that always redirects to the Product View Page.

You can remove the following condition from above code and replace it with your button name.

Your code - `{if (isset($product.customization_required) && $product.customization_required)}{l s='Customize'}{else}{l s='More'}{/if}`

```
Replace With - {l s='show details'}
```

or if you want to add new button, then add the following lines in your code

```
<a class="button lnk_view btn btn-default" href="{$product.link|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" title="{l s='Show product details'}"><span>{l s='show details'}</span></a>
```